# Express middleware - router.use issue

Tags: node.js, express

I have this simple code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {


    req.lectalApiData = {
        Model: Email,
        conditions: req.query
    };

    router.use(function(req,res,next){    //this is not executing
        console.log('do that') 
        res.json({ok:'OK'});
    });

});
```

I clearly am doing something wrong, but according to the docs, it says I can use this syntax:
http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

what am I doing wrong?

perhaps it's because the `router.use` is nested inside a `router.get` -

so my question then becomes - how do I create more middleware for that same route inside the `router.get` middleware?

Comment: *"how do I create more middleware for that same route"* Just keep adding functions to `router.get('/', `, they get executed in order. don't forget to call `next`.

Comment: yeah, but for the same endpoint, if I do router.use('/',function(){}) that doesn't get called..I believe router.use(function(){}) is closer to want I am looking for

Comment: `router.get('/',function(){}, function () {}, function () {}, function () {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep adding functions to `router.get('/',`, they get executed in order. Don't forget to call `next`.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    req.lectalApiData = {
        Model: Email,
        conditions: req.query
    };
    next(); // pass off to next middleware
}, function(req,res,next){
    console.log('do that') 
    res.json({ok:'OK'});
});
```

or better:

```
function doThis(req, res, next) {
    req.lectalApiData = {
        Model: Email,
        conditions: req.query
    };
    next(); // pass off to next middleware
}

function doThat(req, res) {
    console.log('do that') 
    res.json({ok:'OK'});
}

router.get('/', doThis, doThat);
```

Comment: ah yes, that's not quite as clean as I want, but it will work thanks

Comment: Clean would be defining each of those anonymous functions elsewhere with a name, and just passing it in. also makes them reusable and easily testable.

Comment: yeah I will add something to the original question to show exactly what I am looking for, but mostly won't change what is in the OP already, your answer is correct and will mostly be accepted by yours truly

Comment: what you can do is use a functor to return a middleware function from doThis, and just use >>> router.get(doThis(Model,conditions)) ... but what you have is good enough thanks

Comment: what I really want to avoid is having to call next() ... lord knows me and others will forget to make that call and be left scratching our heads more than once with that one

Comment: i love the way `next` works. to each his own i guess

Comment: I like it too, but I know that I forget to call it from time to time and it can be hard to debug when that happens...because the server never responds